# Knowing the end of file in logstash

Tags: parsing, logging, logstash

Is there any way to identify if logstash has parsed all lines upto the bottom of the file. Using logstash to parse STATIC file, so the logstash need not wait/run after it has complted parsing existing lines in files.
If there is no such feature in logstash, is there any work around to achieve it without modifying the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logstash keeps a registry of the files that it is processing (and has processed).  You could compare the offset stored in that file to the actual size of the file.  If they match, it's "done".

Comment: so there is no inbuilt option to do that; need to write some external code to check the registry everytime some logstash event occurs.

Comment: If that is the only solution, then for every event (every line read), you should read sincedb file and compare, right? thats gonna be a performance degradation. Let me know your thoughts on that. thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to run logstash periodically, then start it up, check the registry every minute thereafter, and kill it when it's caught up.  If you're trying to do something else, describe it.

Comment: yeah that right. but name of the registry file (aka sincedb file) is someting random like ".sincedb_89f324fg4f34f34f34", so how to map the sincedb file to the actual input file. I need to parse different files and different files have different sincedb.

Comment: It's not random, but a hash of the path.  You could repeat that logic in your script or maybe just load them all.    https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb#L110

Comment: one more problem here, when reading a new file the registry file is created only after completing the entire logstash job. I mean I have to parse a file of approx 40mb from beginning which takes about 4minutes and the sincedb file is created only after 4minutes (whatever time it takes to complete for the first time). the code is getting dirty; have to continuously check if sincedb file exist and "if found" then keep checking entry in sincedb file at constant interval. Is there any better way?

Comment: The registry should be written every 15 seconds by default.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_write_interval

Comment: right, but I'm not talking about "sincedb_write_interval". The time to create the sincedb file is more.